# How to get the sum of the lengths of all arrays?

Tags: javascript

I receive different strings as arguments, there may be several of them.
I check in the if block if there are more than 1 argument, then I need to return the sum of the lengths of the lines that were passed in the function arguments. How can i do this?

```js
const strSum = (...args) => {
  let sum = 0;
  if (args.length > 1) {
    args.forEach((item) => {

    });
  }
  return sum;
};

console.log(strSum('hello', 'hi', 'my name', 'is')); //16
```

Comment: `item` is a string. `.length` the length of that string. `+` a useful operator when working with numbers.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: What do you mean with _"lengths of all arrays"_? `args` is the only array in your question and its length is 4. What's the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `item.length` to the sum. item.length will be equals to the length of the string.

```js
const strSum = (...args) => {
  let sum = 0;
  if (args.length > 1) {
    args.forEach((item) => {
      sum += item.length
    });
  }
  return sum;
};

console.log(strSum('hello', 'hi', 'my name', 'is')); //16
console.log(strSum()); //0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array.reduce`

```js
const strSum1 = (...args) => {
  if (args.length <= 1) return 0;
  return args.reduce((sum, item) => { return sum + item.length}, 0)
};
```